# Am I overloading my circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, buffer, wheatstone-bridge

[image]
I'm using op-amps as schmitt trigger and with the resistors in the wheatstone bridge I am trying to control the flow of current in the load. When the load resistance is not connect between the outputs of op-amps, I get the voltage values that I was expecting.

[image]

But when I connect the load, [image]the voltage value changes and its not enough to drive the load.

[image]

I think I am overloading the op-amps.
what can I do to prevent this, I at least need 5 W across the load resistor. Will it be solved by using current buffers? Can anyone show me how?

Comment: Which opamp model is being used?

Comment: General purpose opamp can handle load typically not less than 1 kOhm, is is written in its datasheet. Also, not every opamp can be used as comparator because of internal protection diodes between input, resistors in series with inputs are required.

Comment: @devnull
 i'm using tl072

Comment: @Vladimir is that why the voltages are getting clamped,   not because of overloading?

Comment: The TL072 can only source/sink 10 mA at most.

Comment: @evildemonic ok ,can it be solved using buffers

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: _”I'm using op-amps as schmitt trigger ”_ How come you are not using comparators if what you need is a comparator?

Comment: Define LDR range for switching, ON, OFF, noise level, what is a 5W Load?

Answer (score 0):

Your Op Amp inputs are reversed to get negative feedback.

You boost current use power Darlingtons with adequate heatsink for < 50 % efficiency.

A better design needs better specs.

[image]

Here's my [quick design](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgTCAMB0l3BWEBGGY5gOyYMyQBxgBsAnCZiAhUgpJQKYC0yyAUAIYg45EokQAWZL2T8Q%20cSEYTU8OF2iZ8JAbiL4B6BCUgQwsHsnyQERIjjDpiKOZFYB3SgIF8I2iKL2sATlx7hTEAESXjBAullbH1cUTFD8GTioGyjfMATwAhj0CQjbOwB5SjFPECIBCLE6OwAHcUqPERLkuwBzJxcwCo6A3mro4RRnFCaIPPgB0ZHwbrodOFYAJWnkYcHkdJagulyW6ARWdsGuiNDwqFYcTBdjIZuGvYQNCAAZAEtWgAsAFwAdAGcAELeD4-AB29H%20-0u13qMVuJz2cRO%20TkyBA7y%20fyBIKxEKhDjhqxc62GdkcCO6x1mrHQFHWYmYUxcADU2HSiSUNjFWWBaZB6SUksIIklWeyBdksiLMhJeYTuCIkulEn1CSrZX5QllyVrNYrehdHAILDzTcgkrrgsyQoa7BU6CaPGLyrERFAAcgAcwENASIQdERsFh8BsSN7kNB1GEiMIiKZhPhuAJPXAAQATegAM3YAFcADbfD3-L3-ZgCaB4SA4AQIVCYYTOKgAtDx1QBwjYTCQEil2QZ7N5wsoVgOoKmnJBV2T9GQCMt2AWnsWLBgIwNkwpsswcoJUzmTBPCxPBCpuf-TM5gtF8-MBdmbTBfC7yCiUjemBxQjETBgcgIJ543wM8ByvYdmCWKcSSIR1XWJLZul2ap9kggRpy6KCZmqZJumkLYYAOY0JyyJ0YitOCxGtMjolI0ohCmOhLBgVF8hwaIEDWMQOM6WZxGgPlHG4nlbVKK0GQgHANHADC%20QqHAygwlgIEPZ0%20i4MAAH1yg0zANJNDiNNQDSYGQDTmEMwy7AAIzdEZGOQeTLFyQ5snNMQuiQ0dq0kHgJG7FxSLoBAtIEYy9OfIhLOM2B4C6IQKiIMIzNMtg5MkdI6H8rgYOSSLtMgcKzA0nB9miuRyHjRLgvMtggA) that drives 5W but is not 15 Ohms using R2R 20mA CMOS OAs. You can dither either LDR to toggle the output with large hysteresis.  Adjust R feedback according to specs. for hystereis.

- using an Op Amp has the LPF filtering effect of significantly slowing the step response with internal compensation and open-loop gain.

Comment: should i ground the non-inverting terminals then.

Comment: Don't you want positive feedback when using opamps as comparators?

Comment: @evildemonic i'll have to edit the question ,i'm using it more like schmitt trigger,thats why the second resister is of 100 ohms

Comment: The question has  lot of redundant circuits and insufficient into on how to get 5W from 15 ohms  https://tinyurl.com/2663dc4z  This may not be what you want for voltage output or resistance but it's 5 W. Pls update your question with more details

Answer (score 0):

1. Unloaded outputs are clamped:
   Your Schmitt-trigger opamps have a current of trying to be (4V - 1.6V)/100 ohms= 24mA
   but the 10k resistors with the 24mA needs a voltage that is 24mA x 10k= 240V!
2. Of course the opamp outputs are extremely overloaded trying to produce almost 1A!
   [image: opamps]